# Perform a Triple Cut in Python

Tags: python

I need to perform a triple cut. My function takes as parameter list of int, and somewhere in that list there is 27 and 28. What I need to do is to check what comes first 27 or 28, everything before the 27 or 28(depending upon what comes first) goes to the bottom of the list and everything after 27 or 28 (depending upon what comes second will go the top of the list.

Here is an example:

```
>>> test_list = [1, 28, 3, 4, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> triple_cut(test_list)
>>> test_list = [5, 6, 7, 8, 28, 3, 4, 27, 1]
```

Here is what I have so far

```
#find the index positions of the two jokers
find_joker1 = deck.index(27)
find_joker2 = deck.index(28)
print(find_joker1, find_joker2)

new_list = []

# use selection to check which joker occurs first
if(find_joker1 > find_joker2): # joker2(28) occurs first in the list

# loop throgh each element in the list that occurs before Joker1
# and move them to the end of the list
# move element that occur after Joker1(27) to the top of the list
    for i in deck:
        if(deck.index(i) > find_joker1): # elements that occur after second joker
            new_list.append(i) # move those element to the top of the list
            new_list.append(28) # add Joker2


            for i in deck: # element between the two Jokers
                if(deck.index(i) > find_joker2 and deck.index(i) < find_joker1):
                    new_list.append(i)
                    new_list.append(27)


            for i in deck: # elements before the first joker
                if(deck.index(i) < find_joker2):
                    new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: My code only works properly when you have only one element before and after 27 and 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be solved by slicing.

```
def triple_cut(lst):
    a=lst.index(27)
    b=lst.index(28)
    if a>b:
        return lst[a+1:]+ lst[b:a+1]+ lst[:b]

    else:
        return lst[b+1:]+ lst[a:b+1]+ lst[:a]
```

What actually happenning:

- Slice everything after the bigger indexed one.
- Slice from the lower indexed one to upper indexed one.
- Slice everything before the lower indexed one.
- Add all together.

N.B: During slicing, first index is inclusive and second index is exclusive.

Demo,

```
>>test_list = [1, 28, 3, 4, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
>>tripplecut(test_list)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 27, 3, 4, 28, 1]
```

Some explanation:

By slicing, you can get a part of a list. First see, how actually slicing works:

```
lst[start:end:increment]
```

For relevance to your question, skip the increment part. Default increment is 1, just what we need. So, we will slice a list like below:

```
lst[start:end]
```

Let's do some experiments with your given list.

```
>>> test_list = [1, 28, 3, 4, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Say, we want a list from index 2(3) to index 5(27). Simply do:

```
>>> test_list[2:6]
[3,4,27]
```

Why I've used 6 in place of 5. That's because:

> In case of slicing, the **start** index is inclusive, but the **end** index is exclusive.

What if we want a list from start to index 4(27). Do:

```
>> test_list[:5]
[1,28,3,4,27]
```

If we want index 3 to end? Simply do:

```
>>test_list[3:]
[4, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Hope that will help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer actually I don't know a lot about slicing so can you please just give a little bit of background about slicing function

Comment: @SyedNaqi, glad to know the answer helped. However, you can see the updated answer for some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't actually need to know which is which, you can just find the two indexes and slice.

```
def triple_cut(lst):
    first, second = [i for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e in [27, 28]]
    return lst[second+1:] + lst[first:second+1]+ lst[:first]
```